# Django remove/make abstract auth.Group model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Today I ran into difficulties adding custom permissions to djangos auth.Group model. With my own models it's easy:

```
class Meta:
    permissions = ()
```

With auth.Group I tried/thought of the following:

1. Creating the Permissions in a data migration didn't work because the ContentType objects are created after the migration.
2. Using post_migrate signal looks ok, but [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-migrate) say you shouldn't alter the database from within post_migrate hooks. I'm not quite sure if creating db entries counts as an idempotent change though.
3. Somehow modifying Group._meta['permissions'], but I'm not quite sure if that would even work.
4. Removing auth_Group database table, or
5. somehow using auth.Group as abstract base class and creating a `class Group(auth.Group)`.

Since I'm already tampering with auth.Group by adding fields and methods via mptt.register() and a description field, I'd prefer declaring my own Group model; ideally with that name (I don't know how well auth backends work with a differently named group model).

If that's not possible I'll have to create something like `class MyGroup(auth.Group)` or find a proper way to create custom Permissions somewhere in my code.

I'd appreciate comments on what might be a good option/solution.